# Redirect to another page if time is less than a specific date and time

Tags: html, datetime, redirect

I do not have PHP capabilities on the server.  So I'm hoping there is an HTML or JS way of doing this?

Basically, I don't want a certain page to show if the time is less than a specific date and time.  So, if they browse to the page, and the time is less than the time specified for this, it should redirect to another page.

I'm wondering if this can be done without using JS?  Mainly because you can redirect to another page within the `<meta>` tag

Example redirect to Google.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//SoftQuad//DTD HoTMetaL PRO 4.0::19970714::extensions to HTML 4.0//EN"
 "hmpro4.dtd">

<HTML>

  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Redirector</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0; url=http://www.google.com">
  </HEAD>

  <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Really hoping that this can be done without JS, cause JS might be disabled on certain browsers.  Ofcourse, if there's no other way to do this, I suppose, if JS is disabled, than it should redirect them anyways, so they can't see the content.

Any help with this is appreciated.

I have ASP.NET Capabilities on the site if that helps any.  Is there a way to check it with that?  If so, how can I do it that way?  Ofcourse it would need to convert the time to Eastern Standard Time.

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible without any form of programming server side nor client side... And you're right javascript is not a good idea, especially if data is sensible : even with jaascript enabled, one should only change the date settings of his computer to gain access to the page.

Comment: you can redirect with meta but meta doesn't know what time it is currently, so only meta wont help here, also if the user has turned off JS, this will certainly fail, if server side is an option I can provide you an answer

Comment: Well, I have ASP.NET Capabilities on the site.  Is there a way to check it with that?  If so, how can I do it that way?  Ofcourse it would need to convert the time to Eastern Standard Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do have .NET capabilities:

```
Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) // this is the page load, it's there for you already
{
    DateTime someDate = new DateTime(/*day, month, year, etc. Initialize as you like*/);
    if (DateTime.Now < someDate)
    {
        Response.Redirect(/*url of the other page*/);
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of using the dates in the server, not on the client machine.

**Edit:** this is a C# example. I'm too rusty with VB.NET to provide a VB alternative.

**Edit again:** since you said you have to convert to EST, you may want to look at this: [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx).

Comment: Trying to get this converted into VB right now...  looks promising though

Comment: Could you show the code for the line that throws that error? That's strange... DateTime is a struct, not a class, and one of the basic ones from .NET.

Comment: `DateTime` is in the `System` namespace.  Be sure you have `Imports System` at the top of your VB.Net code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any server capabilities you can use moment.js and do something like that

```
var now = moment();
var dayToCompare = moment("YYYY-MM-DD"); // Your date to compare
var diffBetweenDates = now.diff(dayToCompare, "hours"); 
/* Could be years   
months  
weeks   
days    
hours   
minutes 
seconds 
milliseconds

*/

if(diffBetweenDates > 0)
{
     window.location = "YourUriToRedirect";
}
```